# Setting build args in docker-compose.yml using env_file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use Docker and **Docker Compose** to create a containerized app. I have a PubNub account, which allows me to use **different API keys** for different environments (dev, test, prod). To help me build images for this, I am trying to use **build args** set with an **env_file**.

It's not working.

```
WARNING: The PUB_KEY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The SUB_KEY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

**Questions:**

- What mistake am I making in setting the build args?
- How do I fix it?
- Is this a good way to set `ENV` variables for the containers `scan` and `flask`?

At the very bottom is an **IntelliJ IDE screenshot**, or the text code is just below.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` content:

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  scan:
    env_file:
      - sample.env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        pub_key: $PUB_KEY
        sub_key: $SUB_KEY
      target: scan
    image: bt-beacon/scan:v1

  flask:
    env_file:
      - sample.env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        pub_key: $PUB_KEY
        sub_key: $SUB_KEY
      target: flask
    image: bt-beacon/flask:v1
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

And the `Dockerfile`:

```
# --- BASE NODE ---
FROM python:3.6-jessie as base
ARG pub_key
ARG sub_key

RUN test -n "$pub_key"
RUN test -n "$sub_key"

# --- SCAN NODE ---
FROM base as scan

ENV PUB_KEY=$pub_key
ENV SUB_KEY=$sub_key

COPY app/requirements.scan.txt /

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install bluetooth bluez bluez-hcidump python-bluez python-numpy python3-dev libbluetooth-dev libcap2-bin
RUN pip install -r /requirements.scan.txt
RUN setcap 'cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+eip' $(readlink -f $(which python))

COPY app/src /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["./scan.py", "$pub_key", "$sub_key"]


# -- FLASK APP ---
FROM base as flask

ENV SUB_KEY=$sub_key

COPY app/requirements.flask.txt /
COPY app/src /app

RUN pip install -r /requirements.flask.txt

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Finally, `sample.env`:

```
# PubNub app keys here
PUB_KEY=xyz1
SUB_KEY=xyz2
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`env_file` can only set environment variables inside a service container. Variables from `env_file` cannot be injected into `docker-compose.yml` itself.

You have such options ([described there in detail](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)):

- inject these variables into the shell, from which you run `docker-compose up`
- create `.env` file containing these variables (syntax identical to your `sample.env`)

Personally I would separate image building process and container launching process (take away image building responsibility from docker-compose to external script, then building process can be configured easily).

Comment: Thank you - it sounds like the answer is "what you want is not possible right now." To be clear, your preference would be to use a script to call `build` and push to a Docker repo, then use `docker-compose.yml` to pull existing images?

Comment: If you want fast, simple solution, just remove `env_file` section from compose. and rename `sample.env` to `.env`, and everything should work

Comment: I see - so there is only one file that can work here, and it is named `.env` only. Thank you.

Comment: I renamed the file to `.env' and Docker deployed "successfully." But the keys are not in the container environment! Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. In my docker image keys are effectively set up by `ENV` statement. You should have SUB_KEY in 'flask' container, and both keys in 'scan' container

Comment: debug it with `docker-compose exec scan env`. Do you see keys in command output?

Comment: Empty! I'm so confused!!  `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=ef7e949d79a7
TERM=xterm
LANG=C.UTF-8
GPG_KEY=0D96DF4D4110E5C43FBFB17F2D347EA6AA65421D
PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.5
PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=10.0.1
SUB_KEY=
HOME=/root`

Comment: It is getting the build arg in the Dockerfile, but that appears to be a blank string? Or perhaps I am not assigning correctly...

Comment: `ARG` statement must be present in every build stage, not only in the base

Comment: Interesting. I see that you are right, and there is some consternation over this decision. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34129